# Current date being returned multiple times?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a simple query which works as expected the first time.

However, when I re-run it, it returns the same result 504 times, instead of once.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

```
SELECT GETDATE(), CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) AS Casted_Date
from Production.Product
```

Comment: Because it's going to produce the output of `GETDATE(), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` once for each row in the table. What is it you're actually trying to do? Casting `GETDATE()` to `DATE` makes no sense anyway; `GETDATE()` is already a `DATE`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was copying some content from a course, but got this error. The course instructor got back to me and gave the same answer as you did. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `count` of rows based on your count of rows in `Production.Product` table.

This query is not valid anymore to validate since you are casting `Date` datatype as `Date` again.